# An explicit computation of the blow-up of curve over $\mathbb{F}_3$ at two points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves, birational-geometry, blow-ups

I would like to work through computing the blow-up of a particular curve along a subvariety consisting of just two points, both of which are *ordinary double points.*

Let $$F(X,Y,Z) = X^4 + Y^4 - X Y^2 Z - X^2 Z^2 + Y^2 Z^2 + Z^4 \in \mathbb{F}_3[X,Y,Z]$$ and let $C \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2 $ be the curve over $\mathbb{F}_3$ defined by $F(X,Y,Z) = 0$.

Now consider the subvariety of $C$ defined by $X^2 + Z^2 = Y = 0$, i.e. the two points $[2\alpha + 2, 0, 1], [\alpha + 1, 0, 1]$ where here $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha^{2} + 2\alpha +2 = 0$.

I would like to compute the blow-up of $C$ along this subvariety. I know how to compute blow-ups at a single point but I am not sure how to go about computing this blow-up along *two* points.

EDIT: I forgot to emphasise that I am interested in blowing up a curve along a subvariety of just two points, where those points are (conjugate) *ordinary double points*.

Comment: You should be able to blow up at multiple points by blowing up each point separately. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97201/is-the-composition-of-blowing-up-a-blowing-up

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that I am trying to use this example to understand things about what the field of definition is for points on the blow-up which lie above singular points on the original curve C, and for this reason I believe I need to blow up the subvariety as defined above as opposed to blowing up each point individually. I want the polynomial equations whose zero set defines the (two) points to have coefficients from the field $F_3$, so I want to blow both points up at once as opposed to blowing them up one by one.

Answer (score 5):

You can blowup any lci subvariety in the same way. In this particular case, consider the projective bundle
$$
\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1))
$$
over $\mathbb{P}^2$. Let $U$ and $V$ be the coordinates corresponding to the line bundle summands in the projective bundle. Then the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ is the subvariety in the projective bundle given by the equation 
$$
UY - V(X^2 + Z^2) = 0,
$$
and the blowup of the curve is its strict transform in the blowup of the plane.

EDIT. Similarly to the blowup of a point, there are two charts: $U \ne 0$ and $V \ne 0$. On the first you can write $Y = v(X^2 + Z^2)$, substitute into the equation of the curve, and cancel the common factor; on the second you can write $X^2 + Z^2 = uY$, substitute, and cancel again.

Comment: Thanks. I am an undergraduate and do not currently know much algebraic geometry, but will try to learn it. Would you be able to tell me how to go about getting the strict transform?

I know that when blowing up at just one point, say at $(0: 0: 1)$, we can compute affine charts of the blow-up. Then in the affine chart where $V \neq 0$ the defining equations are:

$$X - uY = 0$$
$$\frac{F(uY, Y, X)}{Y^2} = 0$$

I would like to know what the analogous equations are for my case of two points.

Comment: When I say I don't know much algebraic geometry, I mean that I do not currently know about things like projective bundles, and I am just learning commutative algebra now from Atiyah-Macdonald. I am going off a rough understanding of the definition of blow-up from Harris' Algebraic Geometry in dealing with this problem.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, what I am talking about above assumes the point (0:0:1) is a node (ordinary double point) on a curve C defined by $F(X,Y,Z) = 0$ where $F(X,Y,Z) \in \mathbb{F}_q[X,Y,Z]$. Similarly, the situation I posted about is a curve and I am trying to blow-up the curve along two (conjugate) nodes.

Comment: @maddels: I added a short explanation. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Thank you, yes, that helps. Actually, would you be able to tell me how you would go about substituting $X^2 + Z^2 = uY$ into the equation of the curve?

In addition, I would like to know about the more general situation where the two conjugate singular points on the curve are nodes, say of the form $(\alpha : \beta : 1), (\alpha^\prime : \beta^\prime : 1)$, where *both* $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may lie in $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$, and thus we have *two* quadratics $(X^2-(\alpha + \alpha^\prime) X Z + (\alpha \alpha^\prime) Z^2)$, $(Y^2-(\beta+ \beta^\prime) Y Z + (\beta \beta^\prime) Z^2)$.

Comment: In this more general case, how do I go about substituting into the original curve?

Comment: For an example of this more general case I am concerned with, consider $$F(X,Y,Z) = -X^4 + X^3 Y - X^2 Y^2 - X Y^3 + X^3 Z + Y^3 Z - X^2 Z^2 + X Y Z^2 - Y^2 Z^2 + X Z^3 + Z^4$$ where $F \in \mathbb{F}_{3}[X,Y,Z]$. The singular points here are $P = (2\alpha + 2 : \alpha + 2 : 1), P^{\prime} = (\alpha + 1 : 2 \alpha : 1)$ where $\alpha^{2} + 2 \alpha  + 2 = 0$. So the defining equations for the subvariety should be $$X^2 + Z^{2} = Y^{2} - 2YZ+ 2 Z^{2} = 0$$ 

Then I'd have $X^{2} + Z^2 = u( Y^{2} - 2YZ+ 2 Z^{2})$ for the $V \neq 0$ part, and $Y^2- 2YZ+ 2 Z^2 = v(X^{2} + Z^{2})$ for $U \neq 0$

Comment: It seems I kind *kind of* substitute $X^2 + Z^{2} = uY$ into the original equation by $$F(u*X, X^2 + Z^{2}, u*Z)/(u^2(X^2 + Z^{2})^2) = 0$$ but I'm not sure how to do the more general thing I mention above, i.e. how to deal with the situation where we have $$V(X^2-(\alpha + \alpha^\prime) X Z + (\alpha \alpha^\prime) Z^2) - U(Y^2-(\beta+ \beta^\prime) Y Z + (\beta \beta^\prime) Z^2) = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for your responses so far, they have been helpful! Sorry for all the extra questions.

Comment: @maddels: I shouldn't say "substitute $X^2+Z^2=uY$". This should be understood as that the curve is given by the two equations $X^2+Z^2=uY$ and $F(X,Y,Z) = 0$ (up to an irreducible component that one should neglect) in the product $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "up to an irreducible component that one should neglect?". What I would like is to be able to figure out what values $u$ should take when we are over the singular point on the original curve, i.e. by "substituting" (or something like substituting), and then taking $(X,Y,Z) = (a,b,1)$, obtain a quadratic $q(u)$ in $u$, whose roots are say $\gamma, \gamma^\prime$. So that then the points on the blow-up lying over $(a:b:1)$ are $((a:b:1), \gamma)$, $((a:b:1), \gamma^\prime)$.

Comment: I meant that the intersection might have two irreducible components, one of which is contained in the preimage of the blowup center.